# The SSH session has terminated with error. Reason: Error class: LocalSshDisconn, code: ConnectionLost, message:FlowSshTransport: received EOF

Tags: ssh, connection, vps

I am using bitvise-ssh to connect my VPS server via a proxy of SOCKS5.(My OS: WIN10; VPS OS: Debian11; Bitvise9.27)
When I input the certain account info and then login successfully, but it disconnects after few seconds.
It says:

```
The SSH session has terminated with error. Reason: Error class: LocalSshDisconn, code: ConnectionLost, message:FlowSshTransport: received EOF
```

I really have no idea of it.

I searched for this error as for the problem, and browsered several solutions,such as:

- Check my ssh login info.(It's corrected.)
- Check my network and proxy's availability.(Both of them are accessible.)
- Check my client Windows's firewall.(Bitvise is allowed.)
- Check the VPS server's firewall.(I searched for the operation order in linux and typed them into server console, but operations didn't work.)
- I've tried two answers on stackoverflow, but it didn't work still.

I'm looking forward to some possible solutions to this error.
If you have ever encountered the same error or you have some constructive advice on this problem for me, please reply to me.

Any possible suggestions would be appreciated!
Thanks forward.